# C# - TcpClient Timeout on IMAP Hostname that doesnt exist

Tags: c#, imap, tcpclient

So I have a very basic script:

```
#region Get Hostname IP
IPAddress[] dnsRecords = Dns.GetHostAddresses(hostname);
string ipHostname = dnsRecords[0].ToString();
if (ipHostname.Length == 0) {
    responseCode = imapLoginResponse.Failed;
    return false;
}
#endregion
#region Try make a request to the Host, Port
try {
    _Connection = new TcpClient(ipHostname, port);
} catch (SocketException ex) {
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("-" + hostname + "-" + ipHostname + "- " + ex.Message);
    responseCode = ex.Message == "No such host is known" || ex.Message.StartsWith("No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it") ? imapLoginResponse.BadHostname : imapLoginResponse.Failed;
    return false;
}
```

The code above simply tries to connect to an IMAP Server.

- Get imap.{domain.ext} DNS Record IP
- Try connect to that IP with port 993
- Voila

What's happening for either dead/bad/abandoned/parked websites is:

- Get imap.{domain.ext} DNS Record IP, somehow will get one even though it doesn't exist
- Try to connect to that IP with port 993
- Server doesn't respond resulting in a timeout

Now what do I do? I cant turn this down to an "BadHostname" as it could just be a connection issue on the user's end or even not connected to internet.

If I were to just retry here, it will end up infinitely looping.
While yes, I could do a 5 retries == invalid thing, but that's not accurate and could still be a temporary internet issue.

My question is, why is it getting a DNS Record IP for a record that doesnt exist?
And what am I meant to do when something like this occurs?

#### If you need to test, try it with this: imap.celerityinc.com (no celebrityinc.com) and you can see for yourself.

Comment: imap.domain.ext could point to anything, it could be a web server, a honey pot or possibly an imap server. It could also be that there is a wilcard dns entry for all subdomains configured so that it redirects to a web server with a generic "404 not found" page. You can't reliably know if there should be an imap server there unless one responds, there are just to many other possibilities.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren Do you know whats happening with imap.celerityinc.com?

Comment: Try that one in your browser and you'll see that it goes to domain reseller so it would be highly unlikely that they have an imap server for a parked domain. So your connection is probably caught in a firewall or something.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren No this is expected. its a parked domain, but why is it giving me an imap.celerityinc.com dns ip? And how am I meant to detect something like this? :/

Comment: Who ever parked it, didn't clean up the DNS records. Or more plausibly the default DNS entries were added automatically.

Comment: @PepitoSh I see, what could I do here then? Do detect something like this? A timeout isnt giving me much to if(else) on.

Comment: It is not about not cleaning up their DNS, most domain resellers put a wildcard entry into their DNS to catch all uses. http://anything-whatever-wildcards-rule.celerityinc.com/ for example also points to the same page. There is simply no way to know if this should be an imap server or not (and imap servers also doesn't need to be on port 993).

Answer (score 0):

Name resolution and services provided on an IP address are independent.
You get a DNS record because it does exist at some point in the DNS hierarchy with a certain lifetime.

What you can do when something like this occurs? Flush your local DNS cache. Try different DNS servers. Go back to the SOA with your own DNS query solution.

Comment: Thing is, afaik it never existed and I never went to this website before attempting to get the dns record. In fact, tried on my new laptop, still gets a record somehow. Try for yourself.

Comment: nslookup says:
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    HDRedirect-LB3-890977680.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Addresses:  54.80.72.81
          52.72.111.108
Aliases:  imap.celerityinc.com

Comment: What does that mean exactly? Non-authorative? As in, it's not an IMAP Server accepting authentication?

Comment: Non-authorative, as in my local router is not responsible for it. It just tells me what it was told from another DNS server up in the hierarchy.

Comment: Would I be able to check for something like this in C# with the DNS namespace?

Comment: Check what exactly? I'm afraid you are already doing it with your GetHostAddress call.

Comment: With Dns.Resolve(hostname).HostName I managed to get the HDReditrect from nslookup. https://i.imgur.com/pKUWJto.png should I just do a few if checks on this? Like if contains HDRedirect, amazonaws.com then == invalid? or would that be inefficient? At the moment, I see this as the only way.

Comment: Please edit your original question or ask another one.